# How do I cure my vampirism if I'm already at stage 4 and can't talk to NPCs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm a stage 4 vampire, so everyone (except guards) attacks me on sight.  That includes Falion in Morthal.  How can I get this guy to calm down long enough to give me the details on how to get rid of vampirism?

Note: Becoming a werewolf is no longer an option.

Comment: Have you tried the Calm spell?

Comment: I turned invisible and fed on a human, that brought it down and gave me enough time to cure it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Feed. Find a sleeping human, and interact with them to feed on their blood.

This will cause your vampirism to revert to Stage I so that you can seek out a cure.

Comment: @LessPop-MoreFizz: Thanks.  Was having trouble finding someone who was sleeping.

Comment: Vampirism Rocks ! o/ 
Just kidding, it sucks, alot.

Comment: go to the college of winterhold!

Comment: there are alot of sleeping ppl there

Answer (score 1):

Hide in his room (down the side of the wardrobe in sneak mode) then wait for him to go to sleep drink his blood then wake him and he will cure you