# Vampire annoyance

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I cure Sanguinare Vampiris?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37247/how-do-i-cure-sanguinare-vampiris)
>   [I'm a Stage 4 Vampire and can't talk to the guy who can give me the cure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44084/im-a-stage-4-vampire-and-cant-talk-to-the-guy-who-can-give-me-the-cure)

I recently took on some vampires and was somehow infected. I've been having problems in towns because of this. People keep attacking me even though I'm not causing any trouble. How do I reverse the effects and return to a normal state?